# Answer to Question on Hold: Reputation and History Vanish

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm not new to SE - have some reputation on the SO side, and was compelled to answer a question on this site.

The question appears to have been removed / closed (unsure, I cannot see history), and along with it all activity and reputation vanished on my account.  While it was only 3 upvotes and some discussion, it literally vanished (I had to confirm I didn't imagine it, because I earned the Teacher badge from the activity, which remains).

While I understand the notion of the reputation being reduced / removed, the fact that all history / traces of activity on my account was simply gone was a bit disturbing.

Would it be useful to show the negative reputation change, along with the positive reputation change, so that users can understand what took place?  Or some sort of flag, comment, or other placeholder to at least identify the change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design.

The trick is that when the post is deleted, all of the votes are deleted as well (unless the post is sufficiently old and upvoted.). The fact that there is no vote history shown to you as a user has to do with the fact that the post is deleted. I can see it in your profile on [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1488/cale-b?tab=reputation) tab but I'm guessing we don't show you that. Again this is because deleted things in profiles are not shown to general users.

That question was deleted because it was severely low quality and did not meet our guidelines. Answering questions that don't meet the guidelines comes with the risk of getting your answer deleted if/when the post is purged.

As for a history, it's oft-discussed how deleted posts are handled, SE has found that there is *less* drama when the details for deleted posts are obscured. These are network wide decisions that are handled on Meta Stackoverflow.

Comment: I suspected as much.  As a low-rep user, I can't see some of the activity that I have become accustomed to seeing on my SO account.  (The link you provided does not show me, as you suspected, the activity - hence the question).  Thanks!

Comment: He can still see his own answer if he has a link to it, right? Or is that just questions?

Comment: @RyanFrame no. The question is deleted and it's not his question.

Comment: Isn't this a privilege for 10K rep or something? You get to see deleted posts after a certain rep is gained.

Comment: @fredsbend sort of. at 10k you can see *any* deleted post. Any user can see any deleted question of theirs if they have the link. Any user can see a deleted answer of theirs if the question is undeleted. The only issue comes in when a user tries to see a deleted answer on a deleted question they don't own.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your profile and click the reputation tab there should be a Show removed posts checkbox. You should see the reputation changes from deleted posts if you tick that box.

Comment: Don't know how I missed it.  Thank you.